# If one of the eigenvalues of a matrix is zero, can it be said that its eigenvectors are degenerate?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If one of the eigenvalues of a $n\times n$ matrix $M$ is $\lambda=0$, then its eigenspace is just the vector space of dimension $n$. We can always choose an eigenvector that is equal to at least one of the other $n-1$ eigenvectors, making it degenerate. Can this be stated, or are zero eigenvalues simply not considered?

Comment: Zero eigenvalues are indeed considered in the theory of eigenvalues and eigenvectors. The eigenspace associated with a zero eigenvalue is the null space of the matrix, and its dimension (nullity) is not necessarily $n$. If this eigenvalue is degenerate, it means there are multiple linearly independent vectors in the null space that can be chosen as eigenvectors.